# Query and ordering on "key-value" table

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, entity-attribute-value

I have a problem and my SQL is too basic to get over it.
I have two tables:

**TABLE1**

- id (int) - *(primary key)*
- email (char)
- other fields...

**TABLE2**

- id (int) - *(This is not the primary key nor is unique. This is a foreign key with respect to `TABLE1.id`)*
- key (char)
- value (char)
- other fields...

The second table has the structure "key-value".

For every `TABLE1.id` I have "many" rows in `TABLE2` with `TABLE1.id == TABLE2.id`. In particular I can have the following situation:

**A row in TABLE1**

```
id = 10, email = "albert.einstein@genius.com", (other fields omitted)...
```

**Corresponding rows in TABLE2**

```
id = 10, key = "first_name", value = "Albert", (other fields omitted)...
id = 10, key = "last_name", value = "Einstein", (other fields omitted)...
```

I would like to write a SQL query which is able to return a table `TABLE3` with the following structure:

**TABLE3**

- id (int)
- first_name (char)
- last_name (char)
- email (char)

The `TABLE3` should contain a row for each row presents in `TABLE1` and should be ordered by `last_name` and `first_name`

Following the example, I should obtain a table with rows similar to this one:

```
id = 10, first_name = "Albert", last_name = "Einstein", email = "albert.einstein@genius.com"
```

I'm getting crazy!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *pivot* these key value pairs into columns,  unfortunately, MySQL doesn't have a pivot table operator. But you can use the `CASE` expression to do so:

```
SELECT
  t1.id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN t2.key = 'first_name' THEN value END) AS first_name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN t2.key = 'last_name' THEN value END) AS last_name,
  t1.email
FROM table1 AS t1 
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.id,
         t1.email;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29725/2)

---

If you want to do this dynamically and not to write all these values manually you have to use dynamic SQL to do this:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('MAX(IF(t2.key = ''',
      t2.key, ''', t2.value, 0)) AS ', '''',   t2.key, '''')
  ) INTO @sql
FROM table2 AS t2;

SET @sql = CONCAT('
  SELECT
    t1.id,', @sql, ',
    t1.email
  FROM table1 AS t1 
  INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
  GROUP BY t1.id, t1.email');

prepare stmt 
FROM @sql;

execute stmt;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29725/4)

Comment: thank you! The row before the last maybe is "INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id", isn't it?

Comment: @the_candyman - Yes, Sorry, See my edit. It should be fixed now.

Comment: ok, I will try it on tomorrow when I'll be at work (here now it is 11 pm)

Comment: @the_candyman - OK, take your time its 9:30 pm here :) I updated my answer with a dynamic version if you want to do so for each key in the table2 dynamically.

Comment: ah, an addition. This db has been created for a wordpress site, so all queries are performed via php.

Comment: @the_candyman Its OK, for the normal query you can execute it directly from PHP, for the later one, the dynamic SQL, you have to put that inside a stored procedure and then execute it from PHP.